# Zimbra 8.0: Warning create file maildrop/XXXXX.XXXXX permissions denied

Tags: postfix, permissions, log-files, zimbra

I have Zimbra 8.0 running over Ubuntu work fine but I have a warning:

```
postfix/postdrop[XXXX]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/XXXXX.XXXXX permissions denied
```

The problem is that 800MB were generated for this warning in only 4 days.

I've tried:

- executing `zmfixperms` as superuser
- executing `zmfixperms -e` as superuser
- executing `zmfixperms --extended` as superuser
- changing owner/group `queue_directory` to postfix/postdrop
- set full permissions (rwx) to `queue_directory`

And log is still growing

```
queue_directory: /opt/zimbra/data/postfix/spool

drwxr-xr-x root    root     /opt/zimbra/data/postfix/spool 
drwx------ postfix postdrop /opt/zimbra/data/postfix/spool/maildrop
```

Comment: What are the permissions/ownership on the the public and maildrop directories?

Comment: public directories?

Comment: If you haven't done so already, make sure you've stopped the Zimbra services first as the Zimbra user, then run zmfixperms as sudo.

Comment: yes i did it. always stop zimbra with `su - zimbra -c "zmcontrol stop"` before any change

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem.  Turns out that `postdrop` was still running as the `zimbra` user after having fixed permissions and restarting zimbra.

Bringing down zimbra and then killing the `postdrop` task fixed it:

```
$ sudo su -
$ service zimbra stop
$ killall postdrop
$ service zimbra start
```